# Java Date Format Parsing

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to change the date format from a JSON response, but I keep getting `java.text.ParseException`.

This is the date from the server `2015-02-03T08:37:38.000Z` and I want it to show as `2015/02/03` That's `yyyy-MM-dd`. And I did this.

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateResp = transactionItem.get(position).getDate();
try {
    Date date = df1.parse(dateResp);
    transDate.setText(dateFormatter.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the exception keeps showing.

Comment: What dateResp you are getting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must escape the `Z`:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

Try to use this for formatting purpose instead of your provided formatting string. It should work nicely :)

Comment: While you can get away with this approach, it represents a bad habit, and so I recommend against it. By escaping the `Z` you are ignoring crucial information: the offset-from-UTC or time zone. The `Z` is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2015-02-03T08:37:38.000Z" )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
       .toLocalDate()
       .toString() // 2015-02-03
```

## Using java.time

The modern way to handle date-time work is with the java.time classes.

Your input string format happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings that represent date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern at all.

Parse that string as an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2015-02-03T08:37:38.000Z" ) ;
```

To extract a date, you must specify a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a moment after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal Canada.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

You want only the date portion without the time of day. So extract a `LocalDate`. While a `LocalDate` lacks any concept of offset-from-UTC or time zone, the `toLocalDate` method respects the `ZonedDateTime` object’s time zone in determining the date.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

You seem to want standard ISO 8601 format, `YYYY-MM-DD`. Simply call `toString` without need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = ld.toString();
```

> 2015-02-03

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).